# Formula to calculate fastest minute of a horse race

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I though of a problem (which is more of a fun to do than anything else), that it's the following:

Is it possible to find a formula (or something similar) that calculates the fastest minute of a horse in a race?

For example, let's take the example of an English Pure Breed.

If we have the horse weight (500kg), average speed (65km/h), and the distance that it ran (400m), can we know the minute it ran faster? If not the minute, a period of time that it went faster, or even the fastest meter or 10 meters?

I know the formula for average speed, but i don't know how that can help with this problem.

I thought of this because when i run with Endomondo app, if i run 10 km, it will give me the average speed for each km, so i know when i went faster and slower, can we produce a formula based on weight, average speed and distance covered?

I'm sorry if this is not the appropriate place to put this question, if not, please advise where should i put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

With just the averaged and total values, you can not say anything about shorter timeframes. Your app tracks much more than start time and end time and thus can reconstruct a function $s(t)$ describing your path. That function can be differentiated to get values for maximum speeds, etc.

Consider this: The horse could've run at an exactly uniform speed, changed direction or stood still then teleported and you'd have gotten the same average and total values.

BTW: At 65km/h, the 400m are covered in less than half a minute, so technically, you already know the minute it ran the fastest.

Comment: How did you got that half a minute?

Comment: 65km/h is a bit more that 1km/min (=60km/h), and 400m is less than half a kilometer